# How to access members of a List of DataFrames in Rcpp

Tags: r, dataframe, list, vector, rcpp

I have an Rcpp function that includes a List of DataFrames as a parameter - let's call it "dflist." How would I access an element to read and/or assign to? And how would I return the modified List to R?

Things I tried:

- direct indexing, i.e. `dflist[i][j][k]`
- casting on each step to formal types for DataFrame and NumericVector columns of DataFrame, i.e. `as<NumericVector>(as<DataFrame>(dflist[i])[j])[k] = 1`
- casting on each step to List, i.e. `as<List>(as<List>(dflist[i])[j])[k] = 1`
- making temporary variables, i.e. `DataFrame tempdf = as<DataFrame>(dflist[i])` then `NumericVector tempnv = tempdf[j]` then `tempnv[k] = 1`
- cloning the list and trying the above steps on the cloned version

Comment: A really good place to start are the [Rcpp - Lists](https://teuder.github.io/rcpp4everyone_en/150_list.html) and [Rcpp - dataframe](https://teuder.github.io/rcpp4everyone_en/140_dataframe.html) guides

Comment: Besides the comment by @tospig consider _searching_ here maybe with a string such as `[rcpp] list data.frame` to search for ttwo terms within questions tagged for Rcpp.  We discussed this several times before, in essence plug in element from the list first and assign to a data.frame, then pick the relevant vector (or matrix or ...) from the data.frame (which really is a list too).

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks for your response. However, I have already looked at the documentation and similar posts here, but I haven't been able to find any that address returning the modified list of data.frames back to R. As I stated in point 4 of things I tried, making new variables to hold the DataFrame and NumericVector did not work. When accessing the list elements back in R, the data is not changed. What is the correct way to return the List back to R such that I can access elements in the data.frames modified by the Rcpp function after they have been sent back to R?

Comment: can you make a minimal example using `Rcpp::cppFunction()`? This will make it a lot easier to help you.